# Is there a way to get each row's value from a database into an array?

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9

Say I have a query like the one below. What would be the best way to put each value into an array if I don't know how many results there will be? Normally I would do this with a loop, but I have no idea how many results there are. Would I need run another query to count the results first?

```
<CFQUERY name="alllocations" DATASOURCE="#DS#">
    SELECT locationID 
    FROM   tblProjectLocations
    WHERE  projectID = '#ProjectName#'
</CFQUERY>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Depending on what you want to do with the array, you can just refer to the column directly for most array operations, eg:

```
i = arrayLen(alllocations["locationID"]);
```

Using that notation will work for most array operations.

Note that this doesn't "create an array", it's simply a matter that a query columns - a `coldfusion.sql.QueryColumn` object is close enough to a CFML array for CF to be able to convert it to one when an array is *needed*. Hence the column can be passed to an array function.

What one *cannot* do is this:

```
myArray = q["locationID"];
```

This is because *by default* CF will treat `q["locationID"]` as a string if it can, and the string value is what's in the first row of the `locationID` column in the `q` query. It's only when an array is actually *required* will CF convert it to an array instead. This is basically how loose-typing works.

So if you just need to pass your query column to some function that expects an array, you can use the syntax above. If you want to actually put the column into a variable, then you will need to do something like this:

```
myArray = listToArray(valueList(q.localtionID));
```

NB: make sure you use `<cfqueryparam>` on your filter values instead of hard-coding them into your SQL statement.

Comment: So I need to use a loop right? What would I put in the To="" for the loop if I don't know how long it's going to be. I was also wondering if I would be able to access this from outside the loop?

Comment: So would that make an array named alllocations? Would it be just a single row or all the rows values in the array?

Comment: No, it's just that CFML is very liberal with its automatic type casting. alllocations["locationID"] is a reference to the entire query column, and is an object of type `coldfusion.sql.QueryColumn`. However if you pass a `class coldfusion.sql.QueryColumn` to something expecting an array, CF will convert it to an array. I'll update my answer slightly.

Comment: Adam, small typo: `myArray = arrayToList(valueList(q.localtionID));` should be `myArray = listToArray(valueList(q.localtionID));`.

Comment: @CfSimplicity cheers mate: I'm glad *someone's* paying attention (I clearly amn't). Fixed.

Comment: No prob, Adam. Probably also worth changing the delimiter in case the column values contain commas, and also handling empty values which `listToArray()` will ignore by default: `myArray = listToArray(valueList(q.locationID,"|"),"|",true);`

Answer (score 1):

`myquery.column.toArray()` is also a good undocumented choice.

Comment: Keep in mind it arrays returned by that method are a little diferent than CF arrays. They cannot be modified ie `arrayAppend`, `arrayDelete`, etcetera.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're only retrieving 1 field value from the query, you could use [ValueList()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-6d19.html) to convert the query results into a comma-delimited list of locationIds, then use [listToArray()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7f0f.html) to change that list into an array.

If you were retrieving multiple field values from the query, then you'd want to loop through the query, copy all the field values from the given row into a struct, and then add that struct to an array using [arrayAppend()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7f21.html).

(If you're not familiar with these functions, you can look them up in the Adobe docs or on [cfquickdocs.com](http://cfquickdocs.com/)).